# How to get a row from coo_matrix as a dense vector in Python?

Tags: python, sparse-matrix

I'm new to Python and could you help me about some basic sparse matrix operation:

1. How to extract a dense row vector from a sparse matrix without make the whole matrix dense beforehand? 
   `coo_matrix.getrow()` only returns a sparse representation
2. How to extract a proportion of rows (say, 80%) randomly from a sparse matrix? I need to use them as training data and the proportion left as test data.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `coo_matrix.getrow().todense()`
2. Use a different sparse representation that supports slicing, for example `csr_matrix`. For sparse matrix A, A[i] will give the ith row.

For example:

```
In [9]: from random import sample

In [10]: A = csr_matrix(...)

In [11]: n = A.shape[0]

In [12]: indices = sample(range(n), 4*n/5)

In [13]: A[indices].todense()
```